# How can I make my footer center to the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css, web, center, footer

I'm having trouble centering my footer to the bottom of the page. Here's my code

```
footer {
background-color: #FFF;
position:fixed;
bottom: 0px;
width: 400px;
text-align: center;
}
<footer align="center">
    <p>March 25, 2</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Can you supply the code for the entire page, or at least a little more than that? For example, what, if anything, is your footer wrapped in?

Comment: You want container of footer to be center or what footer tag to be center? Try to give image of the look u want.

Comment: And by "centering my footer to the bottom of the page" do you mean centering the *text* or centering the *container* ? Or both?

Comment: I want to center the container

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just set width to 100%

```
width: 100%;
```

Answer (score 5):

[Shabbir Lakdawala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1942244/shabbir-lakdawala) answer is one of your option but encase you have `floated` element inside your `footer` just add 'div' wrapper

html

```
<div class="footerWrap">
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="footerContent">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor</p>
      </div>     
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.footerWrap {
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
}
.footer {
    width:400px;
    margin:auto;
}
.footerContent {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#555;
    padding:20px 0;
}
.footer p {float:left; width:100%; text-align:center; }
```

working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qdVbR/179/)

Answer (score 3):

OR You can give your footer a container and apply this code:

HTML :

```
<footer>
    <div class="footer">
    lorem ipsum dolor
    </div>
<footer>
```

CSS:

```
footer{
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.footer {
    background: blue;
    height: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 400px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:10px;
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

Link to the Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/qdVbR/174/